# Print out Grunt.js config during the build

Tags: javascript, build, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'd like to really learn how Grunt is working and be able to debug it later. How do I print out all of the configuration Grunt has at a given time? I'd like to see the merging of .initConfig, the package file, and any task level configuration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can print out the grunt configuration by setting up a grunt task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('printConfig', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln(JSON.stringify(grunt.config(), null, 2));
});
```

Comment: `grunt.registerTask('printConfig', function() {
    grunt.log.writeln(JSON.stringify(grunt.config(), null, 2));
  });
`